# Blazor Server .NET 8 Preview 6 Default Template Error on VS Debugging

Tags: c#, browser, blazor, blazor-server-side

I create a new Blazor Server project and when I start it from cmd with dotnet watch it works great. But when I Debug it from Visual Studio I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|10_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Do I need to configure anything? This .csproj is located in a subdirectory quite far down the folder tree relative to the .sln file. But as stated it works when running it with dotnet watch so I dont understand what I need to do.

I read that adding

```
<UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>
```

will make it run and I tested that and it works but then Hot Reload is not working which I need. Surely there must be a way of fixing this? This is just the default Blazor Server App template no own code added. Visual Studio Version Version 17.6.0 Preview 2.0